# App Engine deploy gives <h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy updates of my project on GAE using **appcfg.py** but I am getting the below error:

```
Error 500: --- begin server output ---
<h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>
--- end server output ---
```

I also tried to deploy an older version of my code which I had deployed successfully a couple of weeks ago and got the same error.

It is interesting to note that I can successfully deploy using the `gcloud` command.

I have been the project owner for 4 years and nothing has changed regarding my permissions.

Here’s my **app.yaml**:

```
application: *****
module: default
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F4
# instance_class: F2
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: That may be the `gcloud` issue but it’s not why `appcfg` is not working. Especially since I tried to deploy an old code that was already deployed.

Comment: Well, things have been changing on the GAE side, older apps occasionally may need some updates. What was the exact deployment cmd used? Anything else in the deployment log besides the error?

Comment: I used `python "appcfg.py" update [project directory]`. Nothing else worth noting in the deployment logs.

Comment: Try specifying the `app.yaml` file: `python appcfg.py [project directory]/app.yaml`. The auto-detection occasionally doesn't work as expected. And make sure that `python` resolves to python2 (in case you also have python3 installed)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say it but I *do* specify the `app.yaml` file.

Comment: FWIW, it's not `appcfg.py` itself, I'm still actively using it for my deployments. We just need to figure out what exactly is upsetting it (or rather the server side during its operation) in your context.

Comment: I really really appreciate your help. I am also very curious to find out that in fact is causing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172073/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-y2h).

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching information about the error you get and I found different things:

1. Try using the command line [suggested here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp#deploying_an_app): `appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] update [YOUR_APP_DIR]`. Is hte one I found in the official documentation.
2. [Related issue in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412859/app-engine-go-deploy-failed). In this case the error was caused because the code wasn't buildable.
3. I have found related issues starting from 9th May regarding App Engine deployments giving this error. If none of the other options or [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu) helps prove to be useful, you could file a case in Google Cloud Support so we can have a deeper look into your project.

Anyway, as Dan said, having the deployment operations before the error is useful. Try to update this post before opening a case, please, so we can have a further look.

Comment: Hi Rubén C. Thx but I did try option 1 and look at option 2. The project is buildable and I deployed this exact version before. I issued a case with Google but it was considered a duplicate of this case: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65271978. However I haven’t found any helpful notes in the latter.

Comment: All duplicates of this case refer to non-ASCII characters here or there. Do you have them?

Comment: Not now. I used to have them and the `gcloud` command did not work. I removed them and `gcloud` not works but `appcfg.py` still doesn’t.

Comment: If you have removed the non-ASCII characters after opening the first case you should open a new one, since the argument is different. Mention the old case and this SO post so we can track everything. 
Anyway I would like to know the last deployment operations before you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any non-standard character in the name of the files of your project.

Examples of file-names that cause error 500 on deployment:

> méxico.png
>
> españa.py